# Collect a few dozen signatures under an online letter

Tags: web-apps, signature

How can I collect a few dozen signatures (First Name, Last Name - typed, not drawn) under an online letter? The letter should be unlisted/private (anyone with a link to it can view).

The online letter is not a public document such as a petition, so the tools below are probably an overkill (and I assume that their pages are public). Besides, the document I am collecting signatures for is really a letter, not a petition.

- [Change.org](https://www.change.org/)
- [SignOn](http://www.signon.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You would probably create an online submit form and host it on your own website, and send out links to the people you want to invite. Check out just one of the many sites that provide a template for such a form here: https://www.jotform.com/form-templates/category/petition
The link is a "petition", but it is just a name of a category. What you want to do is the type of petition even if you are not intending to use it as one.
People would visit your private web site and leave their names and click the submit button. After that their names could be displayed below the form or simply collected without letting other visitors know who signed.

If you are not familiar with being webmaster, you could find a very, very inexpensive contractor on Fiverr and have them do it all for you.